# Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin not working as expected

Tags: javascript, webpack

Folder Structure:
[image: Project Folder Structure]

app.js, benchmark.js, board.js all require jquery. I just want to extract jquery as vender.js and three other bundles only contain application code:

Webpack Config:

[image]

The result is not what I expected:

app.js, benchmark.js, board.js still contains jquery code (as you can see from the huge file size)

[image: Webpack output]

Is there anything wrong with my webpack configuration? 
I just followed the example in :
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/two-explicit-vendor-chunks
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`plugins` should be an object array outside of `modules`.

Also, I don't think you need the minChunks or chunks options for this use case scenario.  Your vendor entry chunk should be sufficient.

```
entry: {
    vendor: ['jquery']
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        filename:"vendor.js",
        minChunks: Infinity
    })
];
```

Comment: thanks, it was not working because I put "plugins" configuration in the "modules" block

Comment: For anyone else frustrated by this common mistake (typos in the webpack config) I recommend you check out npm.im/webpack-validator

Comment: still getting the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859585/vendor-code-is-still-in-bundle-js-file-even-after-splitting-it-in-webpack-config