# Vendor code is still in bundle.js file even after splitting it in webpack config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

With the below webpack config, i am still getting vendor code in bundle.js file.( The size remains same for bundle.js even after code splitting).
I want vendor code should not be present in bundle.js

Followed certain links, but it does'nt helped. (https://github.com/dmachat/angular-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Split-app-and-vendors)

[image]

```
'use strict';

 var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
context: __dirname + '/client/js',
entry: {
    source: ['./init.jsx'],
    vendor: ['react',
        'react-dom',
        'redux',
        'axios',
        'ramda-fantasy',
        'ramda',
        'react-json-tree',
        'react-tooltip',
        'validator']
},
output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
},
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
            }
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" },
    ]
},

plugins: [new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    chunks: ['vendor'],
    filename: 'vendor.js',
    minChunks: Infinity
})
],

devtool: 'source-map',

node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
},

 target: 'web'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Webpack documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/), CommonsChunkPlugin is deprecated, and removed after version 4. The reason is - and this could be why it doesn't work with you, that it has been proven inefficient on async chunks, and also difficult to use (e.g: when children is set to true, that only applies to direct children) so a level 3 dependency with a shared module wouldn't be encompassed by the configuration.

Please, opt instead for the [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/). This should fix your problem.